# wordpress shopp plugin click on add to cart redirecting to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, shopp

This is site url http://fourwindscellars.com/shop/category/wine/ whenever I click on add to cart, it redirects to homepage.

This is my .htacces file code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/images/(\d+)/?\??(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/shopp/services /image.php?siid=$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I check it showing it has 301 Moved Permanently for cart page, Now it should be stay here but it again moved (301 Moved Permanently) and going home page.

Please help !!

Comment: Have you assign cart page in woocommerce settings ????

Comment: thanks for reply. I m not using woocommerce, it is shopp plugin. I just upgraded WP version to 3.8.1 and now its not wokring now. I mean all /shopp links redirecting to homepage.

Comment: Try updating `Permalinks` once...May be rewrite rules need to be update...

Comment: I did it already. But it is done now. It was because of static front page was assigned in reading settings, which was causing all /shopp links redirecting to homepage.

Comment: Thanks for your attention for this query.